# The real supplied energy for some device is not equal to the energy of a battery, right?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

These are some informations about the Lithium-ion button battery LIR2032:

1. Voltage: 3.6 V.
2. Capacity 35 mAh.

So its full energy is \$3.6 \times 35m \times 3600\ \text s=453.6 \ \text J\$

But if this battery is used in a device,which minimum working voltage is 3 V, I mean when the voltage of battery is less than 3 V, the device won't work.

So the real supplied energy for this device is \$(3.6-3) \times 35m \times 3600 \ \text s=75.6 \ \text J\$, not \$453.6 \ \text J \$, right?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the charge/discharge curves for that battery:[image]

It doesn't sag to 3.0V until 100% of the capacity is discharged.  Note you won't get that in real life, but you'll likely get 90% while it's capacity is still fresh.  [Here's the full datasheet](https://www.powerstream.com/p/Lir2032.pdf).  Also, don't forget to include parasitic voltage drops.

I'm not sure what you're hoping to gain with any energy calculations.

Comment: so this figure show me this battery can only supply some device to about 3.2V(100%)?so the whole energy of this battery to other device  is \$(3.6-3.2) \times 35m \times 3600s=50.4\$ ?

Comment: No I don't think you want to subtract the voltages.  A good estimate is just to use 3.6V since it's in the ~middle of the profile.  Also not sure where you are getting 35m.  The calculation would be current x time to get charge, then charge times voltage for energy.  So 2.35mAh is 2.35mA for 1 hour multiplied by 3.6volts to get energy.  If you want a more accurate calculation based on the changing voltage, you'd need to integrate the voltage over the entire profile, which would be a pain to express mathematically.

Comment: oh!this figure means that if  the battery 0.5C  to discharge,then when the battery is dead for some device,we can find that  the voltage of battery is about 3.2V?

Comment: @AJbotic: The battery capacity is 35 mAh. OP was using a numbered list without spacing between the numbers and the items on the list so it looked like 2.35 mAh. Fixed. Note to OP: spacing and punctuation are important! There should be a space after every punctuation mark and none before it. There should also be a space between numbers and units as in "3 apples" and not "3apples" so "35 mAh" rather than "35mAh". (See SI standards for more.)

Comment: @Transistor and OP.  My mistake.  I misread the capacity as 2.35 mAh in the datasheet where it is really 35mAh as the OP suggested.  OP, the cutoff discharge voltage from the datasheet is 3.0V.  If you try to discharge it further, you will likely cause damage to the capacity of the battery through electrochemical processes.  So yes, if you discharge "100%" of the rated capacity as per the plot, you'd have about 3.2V on the battery.  This will vary in application.

Comment: @AJbotic but if  0.5C is the rate capacity,why  is there still like 20% ,40%,...,100% rate capacity?or does 20% mean the rate capacity is 20% * 0.5C?

Comment: @XM551, 0.5C is the charge and discharge rate for the respective plots.  The horizontal axis, I'm guessing is a misprint and should say "Rated Capacity (%)", not "Rate Capacity(%)".  It sounds like you are having a fundamental misunderstanding of how to read the plot. Here are some links...  https://www.mpoweruk.com/performance.htm  http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva533/snva533.pdf